# python - Repeat n times without considering next values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this dataframe with 4 signal values:

```
time        BTC    signal       
2020-06-27  9007.1  1   --> Here is the first signal
2020-06-28  9120.3  0      
2020-06-29  9187.0  0          
2020-06-30  9136.4  0           
2020-07-01  9238.8  0   
2020-07-02  9092.8  1   --> Here is the second signal
2020-07-03  9066.4  1   --> Here is the third signal
2020-07-04  9142.2  0   
2020-07-05  9081.4  1   --> Here is the fourth signal
2020-07-06  9347.0  0   
2020-07-07  9257.3  0   
2020-07-08  9439.2  0
```

I would like to repeat the signal 3 times after the "1" signal:

```
time        BTC    signal       
2020-06-27  9007.1  1   --> Here is the first signal
2020-06-28  9120.3  1   
2020-06-29  9187.0  1   
2020-06-30  9136.4  1   
2020-07-01  9238.8  0   
2020-07-02  9092.8  1   --> Here is the second signal
2020-07-03  9066.4  1   
2020-07-04  9142.2  1   
2020-07-05  9081.4  1   
2020-07-06  9347.0  0   
2020-07-07  9257.3  0   
2020-07-08  9439.2  0
```

The logic here is that if you got a signal, you buy and the next signal is irrelevant until 3 days after where you sell, so, the third and the fourth signal are irrelevant because they are inside the second signal.

I've been trying something like this:

```
dias = 3
base['h'] = 0

for i in range(0,len(base)-dias):    
    if base[signal][i] == 1:    
        for x in range(0,dias):  
            base['h'][i+x] = 1
```

But I get this:

```
time         BTC  signal         h
2020-06-27  9007.1  1           1 --> Here is the first signal
2020-06-28  9120.3  0           1
2020-06-29  9187.0  0           1
2020-06-30  9136.4  0           1
2020-07-01  9238.8  0           0
2020-07-02  9092.8  1           1 --> Here is the second signal
2020-07-03  9066.4  1           1 --> Here is the third signal
2020-07-04  9142.2  0           1
2020-07-05  9081.4  1           1 --> Here is the fourth signal
2020-07-06  9347.0  0           1
2020-07-07  9257.3  0           1
2020-07-08  9439.2  0           0
```

It's repeating the 4 signals 3 times and I don´t want this.

I hope you can understand what I said.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your intent can be achieved by skipping 4 values when you find a signal and fill the three following values by 1.

```py
signal = [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]
i = 0
while i < len(signal):
  if signal[i] == 1:
    for j in range(i,i+4):
      if j < len(signal):
        signal[j] = 1
    i += 4
  else:
    i += 1
```

```py
print(signal)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If in your base['h'] you have data that tells you if your new signal is relevant then you can just add this into your if condition

```
dias = 3
base['h'] = 0

for i in range(0,len(base)-dias):    
    if (base[signal][i] == 1) and (base['h'][i]!=1):    
        for x in range(0,dias):  
            base['h'][i+x] = 1
```